# Annyang: How to use it from localhost

Tags: javascript, html, annyang

I have tried to run an html/javascript app from localhost.  The app uses the annyang voice control tool which works OK in the Chrome browser on my Win7 PC.

A comment on the website (https://www.talater.com/annyang/) advises:-

> For those who want run it on localhost - do not use link like
>   "lokalhost/index.html" or etc. use IP like
>   http://127.0.0.1:58604/web/index.html and chrome will ask you to allow
>   your mic.

I have tried http://127.0.0.1/myPage.html which loads OK but Chrome doesn't ask for microphone permission or respond to voice commands.

Using http://127.0.0.1:58604/myPage.html gives "web page unavailable" error.

Anyone got any suggestions for how to get this to work?
(I can't talk on the website because I dont do facebook).

**EDIT 1**

Here is the relevant code from my HTML page ( I have beautified the original minified annyang.min.js )

```
<script src="myFiles/js/annyang.js"></script>
```

and

```
function F_Init_Voice_Commands() //... using Annyang
{
    //... annyang object is created in the annyang.js module.
    if ( annyang ) 
    {
        //... Let's define our first command. First the text we expect ('Hello'), and then the function it should call (alert())
         var commands = 
        {
            'Hello': function() 
            {
              alert ("Hello there!");
            }
        };
        //.. Add our commands to annyang object
        annyang.addCommands(commands);

        //... Start listening. You can call this here, or attach this call to an event, button, etc.
        annyang.start();
    }
} //... EOF F_Init_Voice_Commands().
```

**EDIT 2**

It works OK using the URL: localhost/myFile.html or the URL: 127.0.0.1/myFile.html.  But it seems there must not be any other browser tabs which are using microphone access at the same time.

Comment: If you've made it work 1 to 1, it seems like you're ignoring the /web part of the url

Comment: Can you show us the content of your local html page?

Comment: @dievardump.  The entire html file is very large. Editted question to show relevant code.

Comment: @Titus Popovici.  I have tried various permutations of the url.  To be honest I dont' actually understand the purpose of :58604/web/.

Comment: Aha. Now it works.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: ... you set annyang to `true`. How do you want to be able to call a function from `true` ? You have to use the original annyang object ! Why would you set it to `true` ?

Comment: @dievardump.  Yes, thanks, I just spotted that.  I'm not very good at javascript :).  It works OK now. See my EDIT 2 to original question.

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with Https?  https://github.com/TalAter/annyang/issues/53

Seems like it might require https to work properly.

Comment: Thanks but nope.  It works OK now in Chrome with http://127.0.0.1/myFile.html. But it does not work with https://....

Comment: 127.0.0.1/myFile.html  how do you run like this ?